# How can I run python service script like a running windows service?

Tags: python, service, windows-services, exe

I turned my Python script to exe format using ***Pyinstaller***.Then  I write another python code to run this exe but I don't want this way. I want to user clicks the service.exe and program runs like windows service. My service codes are just simple example to check if it is running or not. My run.exe file has administrative codes I mean you have to run it with 'run as administrator' option. But I don't want this way either. Are there any way to solve these problems?

***MY SERVICE CODE:***

```py
import time
from pathlib import Path
import win32serviceutil


class Service(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "Service"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Service"
    _svc_description_ = "a"

    def start(self):
        self.isrunning = True

    def stop(self):
        self.isrunning = False

    def main(self):


        while self.isrunning:

            Path(f'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\1.txt').touch()
            time.sleep(5)
    def parse_command_line(cls):

        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(cls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Service.parse_command_line(Service)
```

***My code for running service:***

```py
import os 
path=os.getcwd()
command='"sc create MyService binpath="'+path+'\\Service.exe" start=auto"'
os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple batch script to start the python script.

For example:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;X:\PATH_TO_PYTHON
python yourscript.py
PAUSE
```

"SET PATH..." is only needed if the environment variable is not set.